# ¿Cómo modifico el estilo de la sección de eventos en FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El título del evento contiene más de 30 caracteres, requiero que se muestre completo el título, pero sólo se muestra el inicio en un solo renglón.

Comment: postea tu codigo porfavor

Comment: $(document).ready(function() { 
  
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
    theme: true,
    header: {
     left: 'prev,next today',
     center: 'title',
     right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: "agendaEventos.php?ase=<?echo $arr;?>&tipo=<?echo $tipo;?>&perfil=<?echo $perfil;?>&prioridad=<?echo $prioridad;?>&estatus=<?echo $status;?>&aceptar=<?echo $_REQUEST["aceptar"];?>"
    } 
   }); 
   
   >);
  });

Comment: edita tu pregunta porfavor

Comment: Ok. Tengo un calendario en mi página, mediante una búsqueda por asesor arroja los resultados de eventos que tiene el asesor asignado por día, en la imagen, como ejemplo el día 08-agosto-2018, el asesor tiene varios eventos, los muestra correctamente, cada título de estos eventos contiene más de 30 caracteres y sólo muestra del título lo que abarca una línea o renglón.

Comment: Lo que necesito es que se muestre todo el título del evento que exista. Creo que debo modificar valores de los archivos del FullCalendar, pero no sé exactamente si deben ser las propiedades del fullCalendar o algún archivo de hoja de estilos de éste.

Comment: Estoy utilizando la versión  fullcalendar-3.9.0